# Base 64 encode a username that contains an email address-- java

Tags: java, http, encoding, base64

I've been using httpClient to try to write a connection string to an https-base API, and the username / password auth is a bit tricky.

Using the Appache commons base64 encoder I am forced to pass an array of bytes to the constructor, my auth should be email@companyName:password however the @ symbol is not supported by the base 64 converter (as it's not 0-9 a-z or a-z or /+), however this clearly needs to be resolved before I can auth....  Help?

Code (before it's requested):

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
....
        String encoding = Base64.encodeBase64String("username@company.com:password");
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://webapi.com/api/protectedarea");
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

Full error code:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:397)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:397)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:150)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:575)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
```

Comment: How is the base64 converter limited to just 0-9, a-z, et al???

Comment: What Base64 class are you using? The two implementations my Java JRE has don't have the `encoding` method.

Comment: Because the moment you include a character that is not one of those characters your Array of Bytes is treated as a String, which the constructor does not accept.

Comment: Using com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;

Comment: Changed to org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; for ease of use

Comment: The stack trace shows that the problem is related to SSL/HTTPS, not authentication.

Comment: I don't have the org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 and the xerces one still doesn't know the `enciding()` method. My version is "Base64.java,v 1.2.6.1 2005/09/06 11:44:40 neerajbj Exp". Sorry, I cannot help any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your server doesn't have a valid SSL certificate.

What I've done in the past for a development environment has been to implement a new X509TrustManager - this is basically  checking the certificate credentials are valid.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are double encoding the string. First on the first line, and then on the third line.

Unless you are double decoding on the other end, you will have problems (and why would you do that?).

Comment: That was actually an error in my copy paste, I had to remove the real values and I was changing the code to keep the encode string seperate.  So, that's not my issue, sadly,  updating top post.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Hmm, not really clear here. What version of the library are you using? The one I happen to have around doesn't have that method, doesn't return a String, etc. I think you need to isolation your code more here and make your question clearer. The exception you are posting has nothing to do with any of this - it is a basic low level SSL issue, not allowing self-signed certificates, or certificates that don't point to the correct host, stuff like that. Nothing to do with encoding, it is before that.